# Expanding ZFS to take up free space

Tags: virtualbox, zfs

I have an Ubuntu 21.10 VirtualBox VM set up with a 100GB zfs drive.

I have extended that to 500GB, because the system is a victim of its own popularity.

However, I am at a loss to growing that to fill all the free space.

Part of it is that I am not sure what I should see when I'm done.
Should I still see "free space" but zfs will just magically grow into the free space, or should I see that pool (rpool) resized taking up the free space?

The basic steps I followed are in the following code segment.

Am I doing anything wrong? Commentary, correction etc please

==========

```
### zfs list
NAME                                               USED  AVAIL     REFER  MOUNTPOINT
bpool                                              867M   924M       96K  /boot
bpool/BOOT                                         864M   924M       96K  none
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_j4opxa                           864M   924M      159M  /boot
rpool                                             47.5G  44.5G       96K  /
rpool/ROOT                                        33.5G  44.5G       96K  none
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_j4opxa                          33.5G  44.5G     7.17G  /
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_j4opxa/srv                       376K  44.5G       96K  /srv
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_j4opxa/usr                      5.74G  44.5G       96K  /usr
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_j4opxa/usr/local                5.74G  44.5G     5.74G  /usr/local
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_j4opxa/var                      11.2G  44.5G       96K  /var
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_j4opxa/var/games                  96K  44.5G       96K  /var/games
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_j4opxa/var/lib                  10.1G  44.5G     8.02G  /var/lib
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_j4opxa/var/lib/AccountsService   828K  44.5G      340K  /var/lib/AccountsService
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_j4opxa/var/lib/NetworkManager   1.71M  44.5G      132K  /var/lib/NetworkManager
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_j4opxa/var/lib/apt               186M  44.5G     80.4M  /var/lib/apt
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_j4opxa/var/lib/dpkg              250M  44.5G     55.0M  /var/lib/dpkg
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_j4opxa/var/log                  1.09G  44.5G      928M  /var/log
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_j4opxa/var/mail                   96K  44.5G       96K  /var/mail
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_j4opxa/var/snap                 11.4M  44.5G     3.96M  /var/snap
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_j4opxa/var/spool                1.67M  44.5G      136K  /var/spool
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_j4opxa/var/www                  1.20M  44.5G      320K  /var/www
rpool/USERDATA                                    13.9G  44.5G       96K  /
rpool/USERDATA/root_pp526g                        3.14M  44.5G      948K  /root
rpool/USERDATA/tomcat_bkjegm                       434M  44.5G      433M  /home/tomcat
rpool/USERDATA/universal_pp526g                   13.5G  44.5G     9.50G  /home/universal

### lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0 138.1M  1 loop /snap/krita/63
loop1    7:1    0  65.1M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1515
loop2    7:2    0 111.6M  1 loop /snap/mysql-workbench-community/7
loop3    7:3    0 162.9M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145
loop4    7:4    0 260.7M  1 loop /snap/kde-frameworks-5-core18/32
loop5    7:5    0   219M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/66
loop6    7:6    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
loop7    7:7    0 386.6M  1 loop /snap/bluej/161
loop8    7:8    0 386.6M  1 loop /snap/bluej/168
loop9    7:9    0  61.8M  1 loop /snap/core20/1081
loop10   7:10   0  55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/2246
loop11   7:11   0  55.4M  1 loop /snap/core18/2128
loop12   7:12   0 152.3M  1 loop /snap/firefox/689
loop13   7:13   0   219M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72
loop14   7:14   0  42.2M  1 loop /snap/snapd/13831
loop15   7:15   0  99.4M  1 loop /snap/core/11798
loop16   7:16   0 124.7M  1 loop /snap/mysql-workbench-community/9
loop17   7:17   0  61.8M  1 loop /snap/core20/1169
loop18   7:18   0 164.8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161
loop19   7:19   0 176.9M  1 loop /snap/krita/64
loop20   7:20   0 152.3M  1 loop /snap/firefox/701
loop21   7:21   0  54.2M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/557
loop22   7:22   0 251.5M  1 loop /snap/dbeaver-ce/148
loop23   7:23   0  99.4M  1 loop /snap/core/11993
loop24   7:24   0   277M  1 loop /snap/gimp/380
loop25   7:25   0 276.7M  1 loop /snap/gimp/372
loop26   7:26   0 242.3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/76
loop27   7:27   0    51M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/547
loop28   7:28   0  32.4M  1 loop /snap/snapd/13640
loop29   7:29   0 248.9M  1 loop /snap/dbeaver-ce/147
loop30   7:30   0 241.4M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/70
loop31   7:31   0  65.2M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1519
sda      8:0    0   500G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0     1M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0   513M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda3   8:3    0     2G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda4   8:4    0     2G  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0  95.5G  0 part 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  

### zpool status
  pool: bpool
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub repaired 0B in 00:00:11 with 0 errors on Sun Nov 14 00:24:12 2021
config:

    NAME                                    STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    bpool                                   ONLINE       0     0     0
      256b9001-18b9-474f-85e9-42f2a4886fa1  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors

  pool: rpool
 state: ONLINE
status: Some supported features are not enabled on the pool. The pool can
    still be used, but some features are unavailable.
action: Enable all features using 'zpool upgrade'. Once this is done,
    the pool may no longer be accessible by software that does not support
    the features. See zpool-features(5) for details.
  scan: scrub repaired 0B in 00:12:30 with 0 errors on Sun Nov 14 00:36:32 2021
config:

    NAME                                    STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    rpool                                   ONLINE       0     0     0
      723a9d83-56e9-d94f-b80a-fc040fda002a  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors

### zpool set autoexpand=on rpool

### sudo zpool online -e rpool 723a9d83-56e9-d94f-b80a-fc040fda002a

### Then reboot...

Then it seemed that "all I needed to do was this"

Step 1 - Run parted
parted
print       [gives the partitions, in my case 1..5]
print free  [shows up the free space, and in particular the end -> 537GB]

Step 2 - Use parted to resize
resizepart
Partition number? 5
End? 537GB

Step 3 - Reboot

Except it didn't work, despite showing that rpool was all 500G as intended, data transfer blew out at 100GB, the original size.

I'm at a loss...
```

Comment: Maybe you need "zpool set autoexpand=on rpool" before the online -e?  It helped me (tho on a real machine with a real disk.)

Comment: Oops. I forgot to include that I had done that.

Comment: Strangest thing, after getting a wee bit flustered with this. I shut it all down. 

Now, a few days later, I start it up, and it has done everything I was wanting. 

I guess I missed rebooting at "the appropriate moment" or "the right number of times" or something.

Answer (score 0):

I was in a very similar situation. I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on ZFS and I wanted to replace the SSD for a bigger one on my laptop.

**### About cloning the disk ###**

I have only only disk slot so I connected the bigger SSD via USB and I booted on a live-usb of Ubuntu. Then I did `sudo dd if=/dev/old-ssd of=/dev/new-ssd status=progress`. When it finished, I replaced the small SSD by the big one on my laptop.

**### About importing bpool ###**

It booted correctly on the new disk and I could see the rpool in `zpool status` but not the bpool! In `cat /etc/fstab`, I saw Ubuntu was expecting the UUID "8EB4-3F4B" for the bpool. So I got the complete path of the device with `find /dev -name 8EB4-3F4B`. Then I imported the pool with `sudo zpool import -d /dev/disk/by-uuid/8EB4-3F4B bpool`

**### About expanding rpool ###**

I found great help at https://serverfault.com/questions/946055/increase-the-zfs-partition-to-use-the-entire-disk. As I have a single disk, bpool and rpool are on different "partitions" of the same disk. So `zpool set autoexpand=on` or `zpool online -e ...` won't work until you increase the size of that partition. Unfortunately, gparted would not allow me to increase the size of the partition so I had to do it via the command line.

In my case, `zpool status` returned the device "732fe207-fc96-9f42-b50b-30ca4a096e77" for rpool. `ls -lah /dev/disk/*/732fe207-fc96-9f42-b50b-30ca4a096e77` showed me that "/dev/disk/by-partuuid/732fe207-fc96-9f42-b50b-30ca4a096e77" was pointing to "/dev/nvme0n1p4" (the 4th partition of /dev/nvme0n1). So I did:

- `sudo su`
- `partprobe`
- `parted /dev/nvme0n1`. Within parted: `print` (to list the partitions), and `resizepart` (I chose the partition 4 and entered "100%")
- I expanded the rpool with `zfs online -e rpool /dev/disk/by-partuuid/732fe207-fc96-9f42-b50b-30ca4a096e77`
- I verified the new available space with `zfs list`

I hope it helps!